# 'Case X do' always take the first option

Tags: elixir

I'm looping on list of values and in the list I have a case to choose what should be returned. The code loop code looks like:

```
value = code &&& key
IO.puts "+++++"
IO.puts "key:#{key},code:#{code},code &&& key:#{value},value == key:#{value == key}"
case value do
  key -> IO.puts "value is true"
  _ -> IO.puts "value is false"
end
```

The log output of those calls is:

```
+++++
key:1,code:1,code &&& key:1,value == key:true
value is true
+++++
key:2,code:1,code &&& key:0,value == key:false
value is true
+++++
key:4,code:1,code &&& key:0,value == key:false
value is true
+++++
key:8,code:1,code &&& key:0,value == key:false
value is true
+++++
key:16,code:1,code &&& key:0,value == key:false
value is true
```

I'm getting always the "value is true" and we can clearly see the case value is false. What happens here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly how a case expression should be working. You put the value of `value` into the `key` variable. If you want to match `value` against the current value of the `key` variable instead of shadowing it, you will need to use the [pin operator](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%5E/1).

```
case value do
  ^key -> ...
  _ -> ...
end
```

Comment: I should note that this is only because Elixir allows you to rebind (not the same as mutation) variables. If you were doing this in Erlang, it would have worked the way you expected because Erlang does not allow rebinding which means it has no pin operator.

Comment: Thanks. This drove me nuts :) So the case is actually trying to "Pattern match" value into key if I understand well? and if it does succeded then -> is executed?

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `value is true`, but that's not actually the case. You should put the expected value to the left of the `->`.

```
one = 1
case one do
  true -> IO.puts("value is true")
  false -> IO.puts("value is false")
end
```

This produces: `** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: 1`

The problem with using variables on the left is that the variables are rebound to that scope. If there is already a variable of that name, it will get re-bound during the case statement:

```
one = 1
two = 2
case one do
  two -> IO.puts("value matches itself (#{two})")
  _ -> throw("neven happens")
end
```

This prints `value matches itself (1)`, because `one` is assigned to `two` and always matches itself.

In the case where the expected value is in a variable, you need to use the pin operator as Justin Wood pointed out:

```
one = 1
two = 2

case one do
  ^two -> IO.puts("value matches the variable in two")
  _ -> IO.puts("#{one} doesn't match #{two}")
```

This prints `1 doesn't match 2`.

By the way, the reason for this behaviour is so that you can do pattern matching with the left hand side and capture the variable for use on the right:

```
map = %{a: "a", b: "b"}

case map do
  %{a: a} -> IO.puts("map's a key contains a value of #{a}")
  _ -> IO.puts("map doesn't contain key a")
end
```